# What is Valin Hess’ Imperial rank?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

I cannot find Valin Hess’ Imperial rank online anywhere. He’s just called an “Imperial officer”, or he’s referred to by his given name.

[image]

Comment: It's most probably a new character, so you won't find it until more of new stuff comes out.

Comment: Per [wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_plaque); A **major**, a **colonel** and a **commodore** were all shown by four red squares over four blue, along with the rank of **general**, although in this case the squares were spaced out further than other ranks.

Comment: @Valorum Since Hess is described as commanding an infantry division, I think we can safely say he isn't a commodore, as that's a Naval rank both in-universe and out.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - So that leaves us with three ranks seen in-universe that could fit but only 1/4 closer to the goal of identifying his personal rank.

Comment: @Valorum Have we seen a Major with the ESB-type rank plaque in canon? I have pics of Gen. Veers and Gen. Gollin (a comic character); Veers has the wider-spaced plaque while Gollin doesn't. Comic art restrictions aside, if Veers is the only ESB-plaqued general onscreen, seems like Hess wouldn't be one based on his plaque.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - Wookieepedia says that we've seen one in the Star Wars Helmet Collection. I'm just having a look now.

Comment: @Valorum It would seem this guy Staz ( https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Staz ) was a major, in command of a division, and had the four-over-four ESB-type plaque according to his comic picture. The single code cylinder in your Helmet Collection pic seems like it'd back up that one, too. Cylinders are odd, though. Veers had one, Gen. Gollin had four, doesn't always seem to be a standard.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - Code cylinders don't relate to anything other than the need to access various ships and devices.

Comment: It's disappointing that Star Wars' Imperial ranks can be so difficult to understand given how "simple" the ornamentation is for these officers.  It's also interesting that Migs Mayfeld refers to his former commanding officer as "Valin Hess" (to Mando) as opposed to putting a Major or a Colonel in front of the name Hess.

Answer (score 8):

The [Star Wars: Helmet Collection (Part 1)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Helmet_Collection_1) contains a list of Imperial Rank Insignia. It's possible that Hess is a general, but it seems more likely that he was either **a Colonel or a Major**.

[image]

Note that the same rank placard is seen on an Imperial Navy Commodore, but it's passingly unlikely that this would apply.

Answer (score 6):

**Major.**

The rank insignia combined with the one code cylinder fits exactly to the description in the Imperial Sourcebook. It's a guide that had been published in the 90's.

Comment: Is a 90s sourcebook considered valid post-Disney purchase?  Has it been consistently followed?

Comment: Can you be more specific. I'm looking at my copy right now and I can't see what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Because his uniform is slate colored, it can be inferred Hess is an Imperial Navy officer. By this reasoning - and because he possesses one code cylinder - he would be considered a Rear Admiral. Were this the grey-green Imperial Army uniform (a distinction forgotten by "new canon"), he would be considered a Major if possessing one code cylinder.

He is a sneeze away from being a Commodore, or a Colonel, respectively.

Comment: Do you have an official source for this information from? If so, editing this post to cite it would lend significantly more weight to this answer.

Answer (score -3):

he is a major, in the picture with the different rank plaques you can also see the number of code cylinders associated with that rank. And Valin Hess only has on cylinder, making him a major.

Comment: We've seen other numbers of slcylinders used that don't relate to the known rank.

Comment: Also, by your reasoning, he could also be a general.